# Generalizing the sequence $a_2=2/\sqrt{3}, a_3=\sqrt{3/2}, a_4=\sqrt{2}, a_6=\sqrt{3}, a_8=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, mathematical-modeling

I am studying crystallography and came across the topic of voids. The voids are classified on the basis of the range of the radius ratio $r_{+}/r_{-}$ values obtained, where $r_{+}$ is the radius of the cation present in the voids and $r_{-}$ is the radius of the anions, under the case $r_{-}\gt r_{+}$. So there are certain terminology that tells the **best fit** and the **max. fit** or basically the lower limit and the upper limit of the radius ratio for which the cation of that radius can be accommodated within that type of void.

Let $a_n-1$ denote the upper limit on the radius ratio (or max. fit) that can be accommodated in the void with coordination number $n$.

> $$\bbox[15px,border:2px solid #444444]{a_2=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, a_3=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}},a_4=\sqrt{2}, a_6=\sqrt{3}, a_8=2}$$

For $n=2k, k\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$, it seems that $a_{2k}-1=\sqrt{k}$, but that does not seem to be applicable to the $k=1$ case.

These radius ratios have been derived from geometry and trigonometry application on lattices as geometrical models. So, can this sequence be generalised for all $n$? Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like $a_k=\sqrt \frac k2$ is a formula that works for every case except $k=2$

Comment: @WW1 Thanks. That was what the trial sequence was. Any ideas to obtain another sequence that also holds for $n=2$?

Comment: I think the physics behind matters... For instance let consider $\sqrt{2^i}\sqrt{3^j}$ and sorting them. Would $a_5=\frac 32$ or $a_5=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$ both between $a_4$ and $a_6$ ?